# Unwanted delay with UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

Tags: delay, uipangesturerecognizer

I need to do some actions when the user starts touching the screen, moves a finger and then ends a touch. Touch began works fine, move as well, but touch end runs with a delay between 0.5-1 sec. Below there's a code:

```
-(id) init {    
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //Adding a listener for catching touch events and get call back to selector method 
        [self addGestureListener:@selector(gestureCallback:)];

        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

        [scene addChild: self];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
    }
    return self;
} 

- (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)addGestureListener:(SEL)selector {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:selector] autorelease];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    return recognizer;
}

-(void) gestureCallback:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"start");
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"moved");
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"ended");
    }
}
```

In the log (last 2 lines) I see this:

```
2012-10-15 11:29:03.609 App[6169:c07] moved
2012-10-15 11:29:04.267 App[6169:c07] ended
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Noticed that this kind of problem happens only when I use 3 fingers on touchpad to drap and drop. When it's just 1 finger (alternative way of drag and drop), it works fine. Very strange.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Also having it

Comment: It also works if you do a short pause moving before you lift the finger. Then you get state ended immediatly. Otherwise there's the delay, like it's processing the last moves - or no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the GestureRecognizer's [delaysTouchesEnded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/delaysTouchesEnded) propery. From Apple's docs:

When the value of this property is YES (the default) and the receiver is analyzing touch events, the window suspends delivery of touch objects in the UITouchPhaseEnded phase to the attached view. If the gesture recognizer subsequently recognizes its gesture, these touch objects are cancelled (via a touchesCancelled:withEvent: message). If the gesture recognizer does not recognize its gesture, the window delivers these objects in an invocation of the view’s touchesEnded:withEvent: method. Set this property to NO to have touch objects in the UITouchPhaseEnded delivered to the view while the gesture recognizer is analyzing the same touches.

Answer (score 0):

I am only getting this delay on the simulator. I do not see the same delay when I am using a physical device.